# stripe.createToken('account') react-native

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native

i'm using stripe in my  web application , now i have to use this method (stripe.createToken('account', { business_type: 'individual',)  in my react-native applicaiton, i want to know if there is any alternative for this method in react-native , using stripe tips doesnt have this method . please help .

```
 const accountResult = await stripe.createToken('account', { 

      business_type: 'individual',

      individual : {
        first_name: values.firstname,
        last_name: values.lastname,
        email:this.props.data.email,
        phone:this.state.phoneNumber,
        address: {
          line1: values.address.split(",")[0],
          city: values.city,
          state: 'France',
          postal_code: values.postalcode.toString(),
        },
        dob:{
          day:Day,
          month:Month,
          year:Year,

        },
        verification:{
          additional_document:{
            front:fileDatathree.id
          },
          document:{
            front:fileData.id,
            back:fileDatatwo.id
          }
        }
      },
      tos_shown_and_accepted: true,

    });
```

thanks :

Comment: The most ideal option would be to reach out to the tipsi-stripe maintainers via an issue to see if they'd be willing to add in a method for creating account tokens. Or even prepare a pull request yourself. Apart from using a bridge to Stripe's iOS or Android bindings (like tipsi-stripe) or building a bridge yourself, your only other option would be to collect the information within a WebView and use the Stripe.js createToken method: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=account.